# Let $w$ and $z$ be real numbers. $|1+w||1+z| \leq (1+|w|)(1+|z|)$

Tags: inequality, solution-verification

I am trying to prove the theorem $|1+w||1+z| \leq (1+|w|)(1+|z|)$ where $w,z \in \mathbb{R}$ in order to use it to prove another theorem. I need help verifying my proof. The following is the attempted proof.

---

Let $w$ and $z$ be real numbers. $|1+w||1+z| \leq (1+|w|)(1+|z|)$

*Proof.* From the Triangle Inequality,

\begin{align}
|1+w| \leq (1+|w|)\\
|1+z| \leq (1+|z|)
\end{align}

Multiplying both sides of $|1+w| \leq (1+|w|)$ by $(1+|z|)$ one obtains,

\begin{align}
|1+w|(1+|z|) \leq (1+|w|)(1+|z|)
\end{align}

Multiplying both sides of $|1+z| \leq (1+|z|)$ by $(1+|w|)$ one obtains,

\begin{align}
(1+|w|)|1+z| \leq (1+|w|)(1+|z|)
\end{align}

From the addition of the last two inequalities,

\begin{align}
\frac{|1+w|(1+|z|) + (1+|w|)|1+z|}{2} \leq (1+|w|)(1+|z|)
\end{align}

On the other hand, by multiplying $|1+w| \leq (1+|w|)$ by $|1+z|$ on both sides, one obtains

\begin{align}
|1+w||1+z| \leq (1+|w|)|1+z|
\end{align}

By multiplying $|1+z| \leq (1+|z|)$ by $|1+w|$ on both sides, one obtains

\begin{align}
|1+w||1+z| \leq (1+|z|)|1+w|
\end{align}

Adding the last two inequalities, one obtains,

\begin{align}
|1+w||1+z| \leq \frac{|1+w|(1+|z|) + (1+|w|)|1+z|}{2}
\end{align}

Since, $|1+w||1+z| \leq \frac{|1+w|(1+|z|) + (1+|w|)|1+z|}{2} \leq (1+|w|)(1+|z|)$

\begin{align}
|1+w||1+z| \leq (1+|w|)(1+|z|)
\end{align}

as desire.

---

Comment: That looks a bit complicated. Just multiply the two triangle inequalities.

Comment: Isn't $|1+z|\le 1+|z|$ trivial?

Comment: +1 for showing your effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is far too convoluted, and so I can't be bothered to even read it, since a much simpler proof exists.

As mentioned in the comments, we can simply apply the triangle inequality twice.

The triangle inequality states that, for all $\ a,b\in\mathbb{R},\ \vert a+b \vert \leq \vert a\vert + \vert b\vert.\ $ Setting $\ a=1,\ $ we get $\ \vert 1+b\vert \leq \vert 1\vert + \vert b\vert = 1 + \vert b\vert,\ $ since $\ \vert 1\vert =1.$

Therefore, $\ \vert 1+w \vert \vert 1+z\vert \leq \left( 1+\vert w\vert\right) \vert 1 + z\vert\ \leq \left( 1+\vert w\vert\right) \left( 1+\vert z\vert\right),\ $ and we have our result.

In fact, I'm pretty sure all of the above holds in $\ \mathbb{C},\ $ not just in $\ \mathbb{R}.$